# xslt 1.0 xsl:for each to get required values by comparing nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

As I am new to xslt, sorry if my question title is not correct!

my xml:

```
<workorder>
    <wo>wo1234</wo>
    <locspec>
        <attrid>accessrd</attrid>
        <attrvalue>nogothruroad</attrvalue>
        </locspec>
        <locspec>
        <attrid>phone</attrid>
        <attrvalue>99123</attrvalue>
        </locspec>
        <locspec>
        <attrid>accessvehicle</attrid>
        <attrvalue></attrvalue>
    </locspec>
</workorder>
```

Desired output:

```
wo: wo1234
Road to access: nogothrurd
Phone number: 99123
Do you have vehicle access:
```

My xsl:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="workorder">        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wo" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="locspec" />
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wo">
        <xsl:text>wonum: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="locspec">
        <xsl:for-each select="locspec/attrid">
        <xsl:text>Road to access: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="locspec/attrid"/>
         </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Logic required is: if attrid is "accessrd" then get the attrvalue of it and if attrid is "phone" then get the attrvalue of it and if attrd is "accessvehicle" then get the attrvalue of it.

To be frank, I am not getting idea how to put xsl coding for my desired output.
Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Current output is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="wo">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ': ', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="locspec">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="attrid = 'accessrd'">
        <xsl:text>Road to access</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="attrid = 'phone'">
        <xsl:text>Phone number</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="attrid = 'accessvehicle'">
        <xsl:text>Do you have vehicle access</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(': ', attrvalue)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please help me how to do the comparision, if attrid=accessrd, then only get that value. Because in my case, attrid will vary. May be my desire output is misleading. I have edited it.

Comment: In some cases, I want to get only phone numbers from xml. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)